# Laravel 10 Multiple Relationships for Factory

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables: Categories, books, and authors: The relationships are:

- Categories <> Books (one-To-many)
- Authors <> Books (one-To-many)

I would like to insert dummy data using factory and seeders.so first i create migration and model files for categories and books

code in books_table migration file

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('author_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('book_title' , 2500);
        $table->text('book_desc');
        $table->string('book_image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and in categories_table migration file

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('cat_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and in DatabaseSeeder

```php
\App\Models\Category::factory(3)
    ->create()
    ->each(function ($category) {
        \App\Models\Book::factory(4)
            ->create(['category_id' => $category->id]);
    });
```

So , I am able to seed data between Categories <> books

then i create migration and model files for author

author_table migration file

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('author_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

But when tried to add factory in DatabaseSeeder for author like this :

```php
public function run(): void
{
    \App\Models\Category::factory(3)
        ->create()
        ->each(function ($category) {
            \App\Models\Book::factory(4)
                ->create(['category_id' => $category->id]);
        });

    \App\Models\Author::factory(5)
        ->create()
        ->each(function ($author) {
            \App\Models\Book::create(['author_id' => rand(1, 5)]);
        });
}
```

I got 2 errors :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `booky`.`books` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `books` add constraint `books_author_id_foreign` foreign key (`author_id`) references `authors` (`id`) on delete cascade)

and

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'author_id' doesn't have a default value

I tried to insert fake data in the author table in MySQL manually but got the same errors .

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: ```\App\Models\Author::factory(5)->create();

    \App\Models\Category::factory(3)->create()->each(function ($category) {
        \App\Models\Book::factory(4)->create([
            'category_id' => $category->id,
            'author_id' => \App\Models\Author::all()->random()->id // Assign a random author_id
        ]);
    });```
```
This should do the trick for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so that's two different things, I'm gonna break them down.

---

### SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table booky.books (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

#### The problem

The problem, as far as I can see is that you have edited the original books migration after you created the authors table.

In other words, your books migration depends on your author migration and categories migration being run before it.

Migrations are run in order so when you run your migrations it fails on the first one (books) because it is trying to add a foreign key constraint to a table that does not exist (authors).

#### The solution(s)

- Reorder your migration files so the "create authors table" migration comes before the "create books migration" by changing the filenames and then running `php artisan migrate:fresh`

```
database/
    migrations/
        2024_03_16_000001_create_categories_table.php
        2024_03_16_000002_create_authors_table.php
        2024_03_16_000003_create_books_table.php
```

- Alternatively, create a fourth migration file to add the `books.author_id` column (and foreign key) to the books table.

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('author_id')
                ->constrained('authors')
                ->cascadeOnUpdate()
                ->cascadeOnDelete();
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['author_id']);
            $table->dropColumn('author_id');
        });
    }
}
```

---

### SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'author_id' doesn't have a default value

#### The problem

As the error suggests, the problem occurs because you are inserting rows into the books table without specifying an author_id. This was not a problem before, because you did not have an author_id column.

#### The solution(s)

Update your factories or your code to make sure no books are saved with a null value in the author_id column.

```c
use App\Models\Author;
use App\Models\Book;
use App\Models\Category;

// Create 4 Authors
$authors = Author::factory()->count(4)->create();
// Create 3 Categories
$categories = Category::factory()->count(3)->create();

// Make 5 Books (make does not save to the database)
$books = Book::factory()->count(5)->make()
    ->each(function (Book $book) use ($authors, $categories) {
        // fill relevant fields
        $book->author_id = $authors->random()->id;
        $book->category_id = $categories->random()->id;
        // now save to the database
        $book->save();
    });
```

Alternatively you could just make your book factory take care of that.

```php
class BookFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'author_id' => Author::factory(),
            'category_id' => Category::factory(),
            'book_title' => fake()->sentence,
            'book_desc' => fake()->paragraph,
            'book_image' => fake()->imageUrl,
        ];
    }
}
```

And then all you'd need to do is call `Book::factory()->count(5)->create();` to have 5 books, 5 categories and 5 authors.

Comment: I would like to thank you so much for not only the right solution but also the clear explanation. It works for me.